# Get Current User in a Reporting integrated in SharePoint

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SharePoint 2010 with Reporting Services in Integrated Mode.

I would like to be able to get the current user from the report code and use it as parameter.

but when I use the SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name, I get all the time system account.

Any idea how to get the actual logged user ?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Expressions dialog box of your report builder you can use the global variable **UserId**.
Alternative, create a custom webpart which renders an Iframe (URL = reportviewerpage). Pass the current user data as a querystring. Use the querystring value (report parameter) in your report query.

Comment: snap, how could I missed that !!!